# How to specify cells to load into r

Tags: r, excel

I want to import  specific cells from multiple excel workbooks. Each workbook has a sheet named as Results Summary. I already have that part figure out. Where I'm stuck is the range argument. I want to import cell `B2:B3` and cell `C6:C7` from each of these workbooks. Hence they both form two columns for each datasets.

With these code i was able to import all the excel file of interest in that directory. It worked with just `range = B6:B7` but not with `range=c("B2:B3", "C6:C7")`.

What i want is to get two columns with 1 observation in each dataset imported into R. Thanks.

```
file_path <- "data_raw/Result_Summary/"

file_path %>% list.files()

file_path %>%
  list.files() %>%
  .[str_detect(., ".xlsx")] -> xlsx_file_names

xlsx_file_names %>%
  purrr::map(function(file_name){ # iterate through each file name
    assign(x = str_remove(file_name, ".xlsx"), # Remove file extension ".xlsx"
           value = read_excel(paste0(file_path, file_name),sheet="Results Summary", range=c("B2:B3", "C6:C7")),
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
```

Comment: When I try to retrieve multiple ranges, I get a clear error: `Error in as.cell_limits.character(range) : length(x) == 1L is not TRUE`. From this, I infer that you can either call `read_excel` once for each range you need, or call it once with a super-set range, and you handle removal of unneeded columns/rows from there.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for answering my question. It worked perfectly. I have a question though about your code. Could you please explain why you rapped this code .[str_detect(., ".xlsx")] -> xlsx_file_names around a bracket and a dot before the bracket.  I noticed that when i remove them, that first chunk returned logical results which is typical of str_detect but with both, the actual excel files are returned with the . xlsx extension. Thanks

Comment: The dot (`.`) is a placeholder for the data from before the pipe infix operator `%>%`. Typically `str_detect` returns a logical vector, but `.[...]` means take the LHS data (`.`) and index it based on the logical vector `.[ ... ]` returned from `str_detect`. But none of that is my code, it's yours. Perhaps you should ask the person from whom you borrowed/copied this code, perhaps they can explain it well.